# MAUI MAP - How to place a Pin when clicking in the map?

Tags: maui

When user touch/click on the MAP, need to add a Pin in the exact location.
I use the **map.VisibleRegion.Center**  in MapClicked event, but its not getting the exact location which I touched. My intention is to find the distance between 2 locations. So need the correct location details.

can anybody let us know how we can get the accurate location which we touch/clicked.

Below is the code I am using:

```
private async void Map_MapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e) {
 //location details.
 Location dest_Location = map.VisibleRegion.Center; 

 var pin2 = new Pin
 {
     Label = "Location",
     Address = "You clicked",
     Location = dest_Location,
     Type = PinType.Place
 };

 pin2.MarkerClicked += Pin2_MarkerClicked;
 map.Pins.Add(pin2);

 // get the Latitude and Longitude of current Location.
 tDestinationLocation.Text = pin2.Location.Latitude.ToString() + "," + pin2.Location.Longitude.ToString();

 double distance = FindDistance(starting_Location, pin2.Location, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
 txtDistance.Text = $"{distance * 1000:0.##} meter";}
```

Comment: Use MapClickedEventArgs

Comment: Hi @Jason, Thank you for the reply. is the accuracy is high on this  values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How we can get the accurate location which we touch/clicked?

As Jason suggested, you can use `MapClickedEventArgs`.The `MapClickedEventArgs` object that accompanies the event has a single property named `Location`, of type `Location`. When the event is fired, the `Location` property is set to the map location that was tapped. For information about the Location class, see [Location and distance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map#location-and-distance).

The following code example shows an event handler for the `MapClicked` event:

```
void Map_MapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MapClick: {e.Location.Latitude}, {e.Location.Longitude}");
}
```